# Como retornar dados de um WebService no formato XML?

Tags: c#

Estou utilizando um exemplo de webservice, mais está me gerando um erro informando que “Response' does not exist in the current contexto”, alguém sabe o que poderia esta errado?

> OBS: O erro corre em tempo de compilação:

```
        Response.Write(resultado);
        Response.End();



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;


        public class DadosRetorno
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ativo")]
        public bool Ativo;

        [XmlElement("nome")]
        public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("email")]
        public string EmailParticular { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("operacao")]
        public string OperacaoRealizada { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("parcelas")]
        public string QuantidadeParcelas { get; set; }
    }



    [WebMethod(Description = "retornar dados no formato xml")]
    public string GetConsultaDados()
    {
        //Lista de usuários
        List<DadosRetorno> DadosConsulta = new List<DadosRetorno>();

        //Populando a lista de usuários
        for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(3); i++)
        {
            DadosRetorno Dados = new DadosRetorno();
            Dados.NomeCompleto = "Nome " + i;
            Dados.Ativo = true;
            Dados.EmailParticular = "email" + i + "@teste.com.br";
            Dados.OperacaoRealizada = "operacao " + i;
            Dados.QuantidadeParcelas = "qtdParcelas " + i;
            DadosConsulta.Add(Dados);
        }

        //Criar um Namespace para o XML
        XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNamespace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

        //Adicionar um item vazio para remover o Namespace xsi, xsd do XML
        xmlNamespace.Add("", "");

        //Obviamente o XmlSerializerNamespaces serve para adicionar um novo namespace também.
        //A linha abaixo vai adicionar xsd no XML
        xmlNamespace.Add("namespace", "value");

        //Configurações do XML
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();

        //A linha abaixo omite a declaração do XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

        //Definir a codificação do XML
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        //Identar o XML automaticamente
        settings.Indent = true;

        //MemoryStream para colocar o XML em memória
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        //Usar o Create do XmlTextWriter para aplicar as configurações no XML
        XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(stream, settings);

        //Definir o Type e o elemento raiz do XML (contatos)
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(DadosConsulta.GetType(), new XmlRootAttribute("DadosConsulta"));

        //Serializar o list, com o Namespace para o XmlWriter
        ser.Serialize(writer, DadosConsulta, xmlNamespace);

        //Converter o XmlWriter para string
        var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        string resultado = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

        //Retornar o resultado
        Response.Write(resultado);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Falta uma referência para o assembly `System.Web.dll` e/ou um `using` para o namespace `System.Web`

Comment: Fiz a alteração do código, já consta a Using Sustem.Web mais este System.Web.dll o que poderia ser?

Comment: Me refiro aos assemblies referenciados pelo seu projeto. Mas se você tem uma linha `using System.Web` nesta classe e sem erro de compilação, então você tem a referência para o assembly. O erro ocorre em tempo de execução ou compilação? Se de compilação, aponte-nos a linha; se de execução, cole na pergunta o stack trace completo.

Comment: Adicionado na pergunta onde ocorre o erro em tempo de compilação.

Comment: Realmente falta using para System.Web. Veja se minha resposta ficou clara.

Answer (score 1):

O código possui `using` para vários namespaces do assembly `System.Web.dll` mas falta `using` para o namespace onde reside a classe `Response`, no caso, `System.Web`.

Apenas adicione a seguinte linha junto aos demais `using`:

```
using System.Web;
```